# Понимание изменения количества ссылок на объект при работа с очередями

Tags: swift

Как понять что выведется во всех print, и в каком порядке (см код ниже)? С порядком я разобрался и с подсчетом ссылок на объект вроде как тоже, можете дать какой-то фидбэк по тому правильно я все понял или нет?

```
// вызываем на главном потоке   
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue.main
let object = NSObject()   // (1) +1 = 1
serialQueue.async {  // (2) клоужер захватил объект +1 = 2
    print("A", CFGetRetainCount(object)) // (5) функция захватила объект +1 = 3 -> print A 3
                                        //  (6) функция отпускает объект -1 = 2
    serialQueue.async { // (7) клоужер захватил объект +1 = 3
                       //  (10) клоужер который снаружи убивается поэтому -1 = 2
        print("B", CFGetRetainCount(object)) //  (11) функция захватила объект +1 = 3 -> print B 3
    }
    print("C", CFGetRetainCount(object)) // (8) функция захватила объект +1 = 4 -> print C 4
                                            // (9) функция отпускает объект -1 = 3

    }
    print("D", CFGetRetainCount(object))  // (3) функция захватила объект +1 = 3   -> print D 3
                                            // (4) функция отпускает объект -1 = 2
}
```

Но вот в этом примере я не могу понять каким образом увеличиваются ссылки на объект, но очень хочется понять, может кто направить в нужное русло? В логе выводится D 5 | A 5 |C 4 |B 3 , не могу понять почему в D и A стало по 5 указателей вместо 3

```
// вызываем на главном потоке   
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "myQueue")
let object = NSObject()   
serialQueue.async {  
    print("A", CFGetRetainCount(object))                                             
    serialQueue.async {                            
        print("B", CFGetRetainCount(object)) 
    }
    print("C", CFGetRetainCount(object))                                           
} 
print("D", CFGetRetainCount(object))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой вывод 1го примера отличается:

```
D 3 //Принадлежит переменной и захвачен кложуром
A 2 //В этот момент переменной object не существует, она захвачена только кложуром.
C 3 //Помимо текущего кложура захвачено еще новым кложуром.
B 2 //Тут первый кложур завершен, объект захвачен только текущим кложуром.
```

Теперь рассмотрим 2й пример.
Тут уже видна гонка потоков, каждый раз в лог выводится разный результат и порядок.
В первом примере мы вызываем все из главного потока, поэтому только один кложур исполняется в один момент времени. Во 2м примере у нас отдельная очередь и она сражается с главным потоком - main. 
При каждом запуске кода первый кложур может вызваться раньше print D, может вызваться после вызова print D но до выхода из print, а может вызываться и после как в 1м примере. И это уже влияет на то что выведется в лог.

А вот уже 2й кложур гарантированно вызовется только после завершения 1го кложура - очередь то последовательная.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, разобрался

Comment: А подскажите пожалуйста почему "В этот момент переменной object не существует" ?

Comment: Сам объект существует, а вот переменной object уже нет - память освобождена (счетчик ссылок уменьшился на 1) т.к. после исполнения кода вышли за пределы видимости переменной

Comment: Если мой ответ решил проблему, можно его отметить как решением вопроса ;)